# Trying to add Spring Security to Apache Camel web application

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I have an existing Camel web application running in Tomcat and an Angular front end which communicates with the Camel application.  This is all working fine and the plan is to add Spring Security to enable authentication and authorization.

I have a web.xml file with ContextLoaderListener as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>My Web Service</display-name>

<!-- location of spring xml files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.component</param-name>
        <param-value>restletComponent</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<!-- define that url path for the Camel Servlet to use -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This references an applicationContext.xml which contains Spring objects including Camel routes etc.

I tried following some tutorials/samples on Google, and added the following classes:-

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    } 
}
```

The problem I am having is that AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer instantiates a ContextLoaderListener, and as a result there are 2 ContextLoaderListeners and then Tomcat fails to start.

If I remove the ContextLoaderListener from the web.xml, the security part works, but my applications resources are no longer defined.

Is it possible to get the ContextLoaderLister instantiated by AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer to call my ContextLoaderLister?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by adding a **SecurityConfig** bean to my existing applicationContext.xml

```
...
<bean id="securityConfig" class="com.datalex.perfeng.tws.security.SecurityConfig" />
...
```

and removing the **@Configuration** annotation from SecurityConfig class and removing the SecurityConfig.class parameter from the call to super in SecurityWebApplicationInitializer

My code now looks as follows:

SecurityConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
      }
}
```

SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    // Empty
}
```